# How to create records with inactive user as the owner. A Salesforce Spring 15 feature

Tags: apex, exception, release, spring15

Salesforce Spring 15 release notes says '**Create or Edit Records Owned by Inactive Users**'.

But I am unable to assign any inactive user as the owner of the record in Spring 15 Org. I get the Dmlexception '**INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user**'.

Also, the release notes has 'visible to Users' checked and 'Enabled for administrators/​developers' unchecked. Could you please explain the meaning of this information.

Please refer the link.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_feature_impact.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd been struggling to figure this out as well until I came across this: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212256

The wording in the release notes is terribly misleading. According to the knowledge article that change only applies to users requesting to have audit fields opened up while doing a migration.  It's not something you can do at-will.

Lame.

Comment: The link no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching whether it is possible to **create** new records in Salesforce and directly assign them to inactive users (use case: migrating data to Salesforce and keep information about users that no longer work for the company) and came across this post. Here's what I found out:

[This article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000227663&type=1) states that it is possible to "Update Records with Inactive Owners" but it never actually says "create". I gave it a try and it actually works. Just put in an Owner ID of an inactive user and the records will be created and assigned to that user.

Answer (score 0):

According to this documents in salesforce Spring 15 release inactive users Create or Edit Records Owned by Inactive Users. But you try to  assign any inactive user as the owner of the record .You can't assign inactive user as the owner of the record in Salesforce.
Thanks,
Pritam Shekhawat

Comment: Dude ! You made my head spin.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you org is not updated to the Spring '15. Please check on it.
If it's not updated yet, you can check when your instance is getting the major release here - trust.salesforce.com

Answer (score 0):

This feature have to be enabled first.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_feature_impact.htm